# Evaluate the following limits if they exist (squeeze theorem problem)

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim _{x\to \infty \:}\left(\frac{\left(\cos ^2\left(x^3\right)+x\right)}{x!}\right)\:$$

So I know that you need to use the squeeze theorem and I know the answer is $0$. But I keep getting stuck near the beginning. I know that

$$-1\leq \cos\left(x^3\right) \leq 1$$

Then you need to square everything, but $(-1)^2 = 1$ but the answer should be $0$. Someone please help lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your derivation's issue arises in the fact that
$$
f(x) = x^2
$$
is only increasing for positive arguments. In other words
$$
\left[ x > y \implies f(x) > f(y) \right] \iff x,y \ge 0
$$
So you cannot directly square that entire inequality that you have since $-1 < 0$. However you can reason through this by seeing
$$
\left[ -1 \le \cos x \le 1 \right] \iff 0 \le \lvert \cos x \rvert \le 1
$$
so now we have
$$
\left[ -1 \le \cos x \le 1 \right] \implies 0 \le \lvert \cos x \rvert \le 1 \implies 0 \le \sqrt{\cos^2 x} \le 1 \implies 0 \le \cos^2 x \le 1
$$

From here we can squeeze the limit by noticing for $x \ge 1$ we have
$$
\begin{array}{ccccc}
0 & \le & \frac{\cos^2 \left(x^3 \right) + x}{x!} & \le & \frac{2}{(x-1)!} \\
\downarrow & & \downarrow\text{squeezed}\downarrow & & \downarrow \\
0 & & 0 & & 0
\end{array}
$$

Hope this helps!

Comment: you, my friend, are a God amongst men.

Comment: @user155273 heh, hardly, I just like helping people. If this or the post above answered your question then mark it as so in order to close the question ;D.

Answer (score 4):

When $x$ is large enough the numerator is larger than $0$ and of course less than $x+x=2x$. Thus,

$$0\le \frac{\cos^2(x^3)+x}{x!}\le \frac{2x}{x!}=\frac{2}{(x-1)!}\to 0.$$

Comment: I still don't understand. Like I get that you can just know that because obviously big enough number... but algebraically, how do i make sense of this.